# Trying install of Ubuntu Core 16.04 on Intel NUC after installation of Desktop

Tags: ubuntu-core, intel-nuc

After having succesfully installed the Ubuntu Desktop on my Intel NUC7i3BNH I wanted to try installing the Ubuntu Core installations (following https://www.ubuntu.com/download/core/intel-nuc).
However I don't succeed.

First, after the reboot in step 6.5, it always starts the old Desktop installation again.

So, I removed al partitions, and then I get the error after reboot:
error: no such partition.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>

And then I'm stuck... :-(

Can anyone help me?

PS: I also don't understand the step 6.3:
3. If there is any directory mounted on the internal eMMC storage, unmount it. For instance, if you see an occurence of /dev/mmcblk0p3 on /media/ubuntu/writable type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered), run sudo umount /media/ubuntu/writabl.

I don't see any folder "writable" under /media/ubuntu/, so I assumed there was nothing to do there for me...

Hoping someone knows what I'm doing wrong or what step is missing,

Regards,
Jeppe.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to install Ubuntu Core after installing ubuntu desktop?

You can use all the snap functions as it is shipped with Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Probably because it's not very clear to me what the difference is exactly... I wanted just to install minimal packages for my needs, but not having enough Linux knowledge, it was maybe a bridge too far... Anyway, I tried to install the server version as well, but in the end just went back to the desktop.

Comment: Ubuntu Core is not a minimal version of Ubuntu but a special version to use SNAPs which is allows packages to do transactional updates.etc for IoT devices.